# How to pass element index in array to mongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Building cart on website and when product is added i want to first check if it is already in cart, if yes increment quantity by 1, if not add it. Cart is an array of objects and i want to pass index of object that contains added product to increment function but can't figure out how to do so.

```
async function add(product, userId) {
      const user = await User.findById(userId);
      const product = isProductInCart(product, user.cart); // returns true and index in cart if found
      if (product.found === true) {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: userId },
          { $inc: { cart[product.index].quantity : 1 }} // not working
        );
      } else {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, { $push: { cart: product } });
      }
    }

function isProductInCart(product, cart) {
  let productFound = { found: false, index: -1 };
  for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++)
    if (cart[i].name === product.name) {
      productFound.found = true;
      productFound.index = i;
      break;
    }
  return productFound;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `isProductInCart` function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code can be simplified if you consider using the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
let userWithCart = User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user, 'cart.name': product.name },
    { $inc: { 'cart.$.quantity' : 1 }}
)

if(!userWithCart ){
    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, { $push: { cart: product } });
}
```

First `findOneAndUpdate` will return no value when there's no corresponding `cart.name` (and you need to `$push` it). Otherwise MongoDB will automatically match the cart you want to update based on `cart.name` condition and increment the `quantity` subfield.

EDIT:
If you still need to proceed the way you've started you just need to evaluate the path in JavaScript:

```
{ $inc: { [`cart.${product.index}.quantity`] : 1 }}
```